# Cannot read property 'login' of undefined - testing spy - Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am attempting to spy on the `login()` function of my `auth.service` from within my `login.component` and I have tried to simplify my spies.

I am receiving the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'login' of undefined
>           at LoginComponent.onSubmit src/app/components/login/login.component.ts:28:30)

**login.spec.ts**

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [LoginComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [{provide: AuthService, useValue: mockAuthService}]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    mockAuthService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['login', 'logout']);
  });
```

Comment: @phuzi - added both the relevant login.component and auth.service code that is being accessed

Comment: The error appears to be saying that `this.authService` is null or undefined. I'd check that it's being injected in to your component properly and assigned to `this.authService`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mock that contains your service values and provide it to your testbed (like you are already doing) :

```
const mockAuthService = {
  login: () => of(null),
  logout: () => of(null)
};
```

Now, you can spy on the methods :

```
spyOn(component['authService'], 'login');
...
expect(component['authService'].login).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by moving the line:
`mockAuthService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['login', 'logout']);` to the top of the `beforeEach` block.